# Python Asterisk Pattern Printing

Tags: python

I'm working on a program task which prints Asterisks in a certain pattern.

I've got it work from 1 star to 8 and then go from that back to the 1.

After it goes to the 1 it needs to do the similar pattern again but it goes up in twos instead, eg: 1 star, 2 star, 4 star, 6 star until 12 stars and then goes down in 2's until it reaches 3.

I'm having a hard time working out what I can use as the specifications consist of me being only able to use '4' print statements and I'm already about to exceed that with my current program.

Any help/advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks very much!

```
for i in range(0, 8):
   for j in range(0, i+1):
     print("* ", end="")
   print()
for x in range (7, 0, -1):
    print ("* " * x)
for i in range (1, 8):
    for i in range(2, i+2):
       print("* ", end="")
    print()
```

[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cpZf.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of (or in addition to) describing your expected output in words, can you show a graphic depiction of the result you're hoping to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: I added a photo link at the bottom. Thanks @ggorlen

Comment: @pythonB And your problem is that you are restricted to use the `print()` statement only 4 times (instead of your current 5)?

Comment: Why not use the string multiplication trick for all the loops? E.g. for the first loop replace it with `print("* " * (i + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,9,1):
 print('*'*i)

for i in range(8,0,-1):
 print('*'*i)

for i in range(2,12,2):
 print('*'*i)

for i in range(12,0,-2):
 print('*'*i)
```

output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
******** #first loop
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
** #second loop
****
******
********
********** #third loop
************
**********
********
******
****
** #fourth loop
```

you can adjust the numbers if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend putting the whole thing in a loop (if i understand what you're after)

```
time = range(3)

count = 0

for times in time:
    count = count + 1
    for i in range(8):
        print("* "*(i * count))
    for x in range (6, 0, -1):
        print ("* " * (x * count))
```

This will loop though the pattern as many times as given in time = range adding 1 to the pattern each time.

The code above outputs,

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
* 

* * 
* * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * 
* * 

* * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * *
```

I hope this is what you had in mind, sorry if I didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

4 loops with 4 prints:

```
for i in range(1, 8, 1):
    print(i * "* ")
for j in range(8, 0, -1):
    print(j * "* ")
for k in range(2, 14, 2):
    print(k * "* ")
for l in range(9, 1, -3):
    print(l * "* ")
```

Which results in:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
* 
* * 
* * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * *
```

Answer (score 0):

for printing this type of pattern for any number :
u have to just run 4 independent loops :

```
n = 8 
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(i*"*")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print((n+1-i)*"*")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(i*"**")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print((n+1-i)*"**")
```

```html
<pre>
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
**
****
******
********
**********
************
**************
****************
****************
**************
************
**********
********
******
****
**
</pre>
```